# Click chaining jquery

Tags: jquery

I make a sample "Tree view" plugin on jquery (homework assignment), but i'm having a bit of problem : here is code :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.TreeView = function() {
        $("ul li").children().css("display","none");

        $("li").on("click", function() {
                $(this).siblings().find("*").css("display", "none");    
                $(this).children().css("display", "block");
                $(this).children().children().css("display", "block");
                console.log($(this).children()[0]);

        });

        $(this).on("mouseover", function() {
            $(".hover").removeClass("hover");
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        });

        $(this).on("mouseout", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");   
        });

        $("li").css("cursor", "pointer");

        return this;    
    };  
}(jQuery));
```

sample html partly:

```
<ul id="example-ul">
        <li> Item 1 
        </li>
        <li> Item 2 
            <ul>
                <li> Item 2.1 </li>
                <li> Item 2.2  
                    <ul>
                        <li> Item 2.2.1 </li>
                        <li> Item 2.2.2 
                            <ul>
                                <li> Item 2.2.2.1 </li>
                                <li> Item 2.2.2.2 
                                    <ul id="asd">
                                        <li> Item 2.2.2.2.1 </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        Item 3 

            <ul>
                <li> Item 3.1
                    <ul>
                        <li> Item 3.3.1 </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> Item 3.2 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- scripts -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Example
        $("#example-ul").TreeView();    
    </script>
```

so the problem i'm facing is "chaining" on click, i want to display only children elements (on console), but on every click i get the "previous" child elements and new one - i want to visualize only current ones.

Comment: So for instance, if you click on Item 2.2.2, you want to see only Item 2.2.2, Item 2.2, and Item 2?  NOT Item 2.2.1, item 2.1 and Item 1, even though they're semantically organized as siblings or parent siblings?

Comment: No, i want for example (Item 2.2.2) to see only Item 2.2.2.1

Comment: So you want to expand only the inner most item without expanding the parents?

Comment: Just use `$("li").click(function () { })` instead of `.on("click", function() { })`...

Comment: jsfiddle to help you get help:  http://jsfiddle.net/yfXvJ/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but without jQuery its not working properly

Comment: jQuery should be in the fiddle...  working OK here.  Anyway, the first answer is correct.  I didn't understand what you meant :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to stop the propagation of the event. That can be done by adding the following code to the event handler [`evt.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). With this modification your click handler would be:

```
    ...
    $("li").on("click", function (evt) {
        $(this).siblings().find("*").css("display", "none");
        $(this).children().css("display", "block");
        $(this).children().children().css("display", "block");
        console.log($(this).children()[0]);
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
    ...
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6NuP/) for the modification.

Comment: OHHH!  He/she wants to only see the inner most children in the CONSOLE.  I thought he/she meant to display on the screen.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for. I will select your answer soon.